# Using Mootools/Javascript to parse shortcode

Tags: javascript, mootools

I need to use a string/shortcode in a CMS text area to define a button... something simple for non-technical users like:

[button text="Click Here" href="http://www.google.com"]

Based on that string, I need to dynamically create a button using mootools (or javascript in general) on the front end (jquery isn't avaialble in our environment).  So far, I haven't been able to parse code starting with brackets and then grab those attributes for use in code.  I will then need to destroy the original shortcode.   It doesn't have to be setup exactly the way I have it above if there is a better way...Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I was about to solve my issue by doing some server-side scripting to reformat the shortcode-style string into a valid DOM element.  Once i had it as a DOM element, I used Mootools to do the manipulation.

Comment: Isn't it great to solve your own problems? Feel free to detail your process as an answer, and accept it, so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up...  It's a bit of a hack, but it worked.  The CMS that I am working with is Coldfusion-based, but the method should be transferrable...

Another complexity: In our case, we needed the editable button to appear in a place separate from the editable area of the template.  Basically, we had a non-editable button in a sidebar that we wanted to make easily editable from the main content area.  So, if the user defines a button, we would replace the sidebar button with a user-defined button.  So I have an extra step where I used mootools to grab the button that is created, replace the button in the sidebar on the page and then destroy the original button.

The goal was for a user to enter a short-code somewhere in a text area in the CMS, something like:

```
[button id="override-button" title="XXX" href="YYY"][/button]
```

The backend would translate this into a DOM element, and the on the front end, we would use mootools to position the button where it needs to be and then destroy the original markup.

First, I searched for the code in the DB output...

```
<cfset find1='\[button'>    <!-- open-->
<cfset find2='\]\[/button]'>    <!-- close -->
```

Next, using regular expression replace in coldfusion, I replaced the first instance of the button with the markup... (rs.body refers the body data returned from the database)...

```
<cfset replace1 = "<button">
<cfset replace2 = "></button>">
<cfset rs.body=#REReplace(rs.body,find1,replace1,"ONE")#>
<cfset rs.body=#REReplace(rs.body,find2,replace2,"ONE")#>
```

So, the resulting markup would be:

```
<button id="override-button" title="XXX" href="YYY"></button>
```

Next, I used mootools to manipulate that DOM element.  As mentioned, there was already a button in the sidebar with the id "open-form-button," so this grabs that button and replaces the text and link with the attributes defined above, then destroys the element defined above.

```
var overrideBtn = $('override-button');
var overrideBtn_title,overrideBtn_href = null;

if (overrideBtn) {
overrideBtn_title = overrideBtn.getProperty('title');
overrideBtn_href = overrideBtn.getProperty('href');

if (overrideBtn_title && overrideBtn_href)
{
    $('open-form-button').set('text', overrideBtn_title);
    $('open-form-button').setProperty('href',overrideBtn_href);
    overrideBtn.dispose();
}
}
```

And that's it.  I don't know how helpful this will be to anyone else, but since Julian suggested I post my solution, I hope it helps someone along the way!  Good luck!